# Enter hidden password in python

Tags: python, passwords

I want to use:

```
import getpass
password = getpass.getpass("Enter your password:")
print password
```

On winx64 using python 2.7...
The 2nd line hangs. 
I dont see the dialog. " Enter your password:"

Comment: Syntax looks okay, have you checked for open bugs reports around this?

Comment: How are you running the script? Is this being run on the MS-DOS command line?

Comment: This doesn't pop up a dialog.  It prompts inside the console.

Comment: P.S.: If a program "hangs" when prompting for user input, it usually means the prompt is being printed somewhere you can't see and it's waiting for input.

Comment: If this is your entire code, how are you running it? Calling from a script, directly in the IDE? Either way I use these exact lines on my Win x64 Python 2.7 box, I get the expected behavior of the 'Enter password:' *prompt* on the commandline.

Comment: @penguincoder...checked works form CLI MS-DOS command line..

Comment: Ok work in ipython standalone. fails in ipython inside spyder

Comment: Weird. Script runs launched from .py file, but fails within spyder.

Comment: `getpass`behavior depends on directly manipulation of the terminal - not just stdin and stdout streams - spyder probably hides/does not use the terminal - just pipes stdin/stdout to its own console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment above, you are actually using ipython within spyder. The only issue I came across for getpass in Spyder is at their [Google code](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=693&q=getpass&colspec=ID%20MS%20Stars%20Priority%20Modified%20Cat%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary) page. The issues is not *exactly* the same as yours, but included in the comments is the following code snippet:

```
def spyder_getpass(prompt='Password: '):
  set_spyder_echo(False)
  password = raw_input(prompt)
  set_spyder_echo(True)
  return password
```

Try using the method above (utilizing raw_input instead of getpass) to get the required password you need.

Comment: does not work, All I want is password entered not echoed. I dont want fetch of password.. the 'set_''s didnt work.

Comment: @merlin Can you explain why the above code does not work to be entered and not echoed? You would use the above function when requesting the password in your code. ` userpassword = spyder_getpass()` , etc. Don't call your own `input` or anything to do with `getpass`.

Comment: using above, and then calling it with spyder_getpass(), i get error... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\untitled6.py", line 14, in <module>
    spyder_getpass()
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\untitled6.py", line 9, in spyder_getpass
    set_spyder_echo(False)
NameError: global name 'set_spyder_echo' is not defined

Comment: See the bottom of the linked code.google.com post (#5), where it is stated: "This would require one hour to implement. But I don't know when I will have so much time ahead to do this." Implied that no function `set_spyder_echo` exists.

Answer (score 2):

As the other comments already indicated, you have to run this script within the Power Shell to actually see the `"Enter your password:"` text and be able to enter a password.